# Google Fit API unavailable?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

I've created a project in Google Developer Console to access Google Fit API but when I wanted to add scope in the OAuth consent screen, no scopes from the Fitness API are available even though the API has been enabled.

[Fitness API overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBhV.png)

[OAuth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq0vD.png)

Could anyone let me know what might go wrong here? Is the API still available?

Thanks in advance,

Kemal

Comment: Hi Kemal, is this still an issue for you? Are you still unable to see Fitness API scopes?

Comment: Hi Andy, no, it's no longer an issue. I can now see the scopes in the consent screen and the API is also now visible in the OAuth 2.0 Playground. Not sure what the reason was behind the disappearance, but seems the API was made publicly available again.